# Evaluation map defined on Linear space of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

This is from Berkeley problems.(not the actual one- but a part)

Given that  p,q,r,s are polynomials of degree at most 3 with $p(1)=q(1)=r(1)=s(1)=0$. what can we say about the linear dependency of these 4 polynomials ?
Solution given is in these lines :

Let the evaluation map F defined as $F(t)=t(1)$ where $t$ is a polynomial.The evaluation map that assigns to each polynomial its value at 1 is a nonzero linear functional on the linear space of polynomials of degree at most 4. This leads to the argument that Kernel of $F$ is of dimension 3.Hence given polynomials are linearly dependent.

How can we say that $F$ is of defined on the linear space of polynomials of degree at most 4 ? we can define it for linear spaces of polynomials of any degree ? Only thing given in the question is about degree of the 4 polynomials given (at most 3).

If  degree of $F$ is at most 4 then dimension of domain of $F$ will be 4.Then I can claim that nullity of $F$ is 3. This possible due to rank nullity theorem as rank  of $F$ is 1.

By given information $p,q,r,s$ are in Kernel of $F$. Being 4 vectors in a 3 dimensional space they are linearly dependent

Comment: What do you mean by "degree"?

Comment: Sorry It was my mistake....The evaluation map that assigns to each polynomial its value at 1 is a nonzero linear functional on the linear space of polynomials of degree at most 4..I will edit the question... thanks

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Also, you refer to the "degree of $F$", which I think is not what you mean.

Comment: Sorry there were some mistakes in the solution provided.I was trying to understand the solution.Now I tried my self and corrected the mistakes.